# tmpfile and gzip combination problem

Tags: python, gzip, base64

I have problem with this code:

```
file = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='wrb')
file.write(base64.b64decode(data))
file.flush()
os.fsync(file)
# file.seek(0)
f = gzip.GzipFile(mode='rb', fileobj=file)
print f.read()
```

I dont know why it doesn't print out anything. If I uncomment file.seek then error occurs:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/gzip.py", line 263, in _read
    self._read_gzip_header()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/gzip.py", line 162, in _read_gzip_header
    magic = self.fileobj.read(2)
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Just for information this version works fine:

```
x = open("test.gzip", 'wb')
x.write(base64.b64decode(data))
x.close()
f = gzip.GzipFile('test.gzip', 'rb')
print f.read()
```

EDIT: For wrb problem. It doesn't give me an error when initialize it. Python 2.5.2.

```
>>> t = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode="wrb")
>>> t.write("test")
>>> t.seek(0)
>>> t.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`'wrb'` is not a valid mode.

This works fine:

```
import tempfile
import gzip

with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+b') as f:
    f.write(data.decode('base64'))
    f.flush()
    f.seek(0)
    gzf = gzip.GzipFile(mode='rb', fileobj=f)
    print gzf.read()
```

Comment: Thanks! And tempfile doesn't report this. Maybe I should report this?

Comment: @Vojtech R. It does. Try a barebones `fhandle=tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='wrb')` (it returns an OSError Errno22 Invalid argument...)

Comment: @ChristopheD. I added example to question. No error until .read().

Comment: @Vojtech R: I can't reproduce this here at work (Python 2.6, Windows). May be OS specific (I'll check with a mac this evening)

Comment: @ChristopheD: So this weird behavior I can produce on Python 2.5, on Python 2.6 it raise Error.

Answer (score 2):

Some tips:

- You can't `.seek(0)` or `.read()` a gzip file in `wrb` mode or `wb` or `w+b`. GzipFile class `__init__` set itself to `READ` or `WRITE` only by looking at the first character of `wrb` (set itself to `WRITE` for this case).
- When doing `f = gzip.GzipFile(mode='rb', fileobj=file)` your real file is `file` not `f`, I understood that after reading GzipFile class definition.

A working example for me was:

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

import gzip


with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', delete=True, suffix='.txt.gz', prefix='f') as t_file:
    gzip_file = gzip.GzipFile(mode='wb', fileobj=t_file)
    gzip_file.write('SOMETHING HERE')
    gzip_file.close()
    t_file.seek(0)

    # Do something here with your t_file, maybe send it to an external storage or:
    print t_file.read()
```

I hope this can be useful for someone out there, took a lot of my time to make it work.